# Two Step "Fixed" Status

Tags: youtrack

Is it possible for only managers to be allowed to mark tasks as any closed status?
We are running into an issue where some staff close an issue that shouldn't have been closed.
I simply need a way for only team leads have to ability to close an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pachonk, yes, it is possible. You have two options:

1. Make `State` field private and grant "Update Issue Private Fields" permission to the managers only and "Read Issue Private Fields" both to the staff and the managers. In this case only managers will be able to update `State` field.
2. Write a workflow rule that will prohibit setting `State` to `#Resolved` for non-managers (in this case you need to have a role `Managers` granted to your managers and only them):

`when issue.becomesResolved() { 
  assert loggedInUser.hasRole("Managers"): "Only managers can close issues!"; 
}`

Comment: How can I add that to a workflow? Do I need the editor?

Comment: @Pachonk Yes, you need a Workflow Editor. It can be downloaded here: https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/download/get_youtrack.html . Please refer to YouTrack documentation for set up details and language reference: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD65/YouTrack+Workflow+Editor .